# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar la instalación docker.io?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

[image: No me deja realizar la instalación]

cuando realizo la ejecución del código docker.io me indica que las dependencias son incumplidas

Comment: Buscas un tutorial o tienes un problema al instalar? especifica en tu pregunta, revisa [ask].

Comment: @Jorgesys Tengo un problema al realizar la instalación por medio del cliente ya que me dice que las dependencias son incumplidas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**docker.io** es un paquete obsoleto para instalar docker, la [documentación actual](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#docker-ee-customers) sugiere instalar el paquete **docker-ce**.

De hecho el primer paso que sugiere es desinstalar las versiones viejas de docker:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
```

Luego para instalar **docker-ce**:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates \
  curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg |\
  sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository \
  "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) \
  stable"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

Comment: Gracias!!!
Si lo cheque y así es, se debe volver a instalar docker e instalar docker-ce